# Magneto Insert Data into Wordpress wp_users & wp_usermeta tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, magento

At this time, I'm retrieving data from Magento checkout and inserting data into the wp_users table - user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_registered, user_status, display_name columns.

I need to also insert data into wp_usermeta at the same time.  I'll need to retrieve the wp_users ID and insert into the wp_usermeta table - user_id column.

Also insert into wp_usermeta table in the meta_key column session_tokens.

The questions are:

1. What would be the best way to create the wordpress session cookie and for the wp_usermeta table - meta_key column - session_tokens for each registered user? Can someone show me an example?
2. What would be the best way to retrieve the wp_users ID and insert it in the  wp_usermeta table - user_id column? Would a join be best?  Can someone show me an example if that's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered writing a simple Wordpress plugin that would achieve these requirements? You could call it via a query string and pass the data across.

wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );

This will return a userID

```
add_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );
```

This will store the meta

I think you'd have a far easier time using these functions than figuring how to work directly with the database. The other thing to consider is this approach would work as Wordpress is updated. If the database structure changed the functions would most likely still work.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The problem here is I can't use add_user_meta in magento.  I'm grabbing the data from Magento and going directly to wordpress inserting the data.  Magento doesn't know what add_user_meta is.  Is there a way to make Magento look at a wordpress file that has insert commands in it?

Comment: Oh your saying create a plugin to communicate with Magento, right?  Is there a plugin you're aware of?  I'm not a wordpress developer.  Not even sure how I would call this plugin from the magento side.  Any tutorials you can direct me to?

Comment: My approach would require you to POST the data to a URL that a Wordpress plugin, you've written, would handle and then execute these functions. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Yes that's possible coming from the magento checkout.  I don't know how to create the plugin and how to create a session variable.  I'm looking at the code to do that in wordpress, if this app is actually using it, but it's 2500 lines of code.

Comment: What do you need the session variable for? Creating the plugin is relatively simple. I have to give WP development team credit for this. This tutorial may help you: https://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/

Comment: Well the wp app was created by someone else but there's a login created they login so assuming it's for that session.

Comment: Is the user redirected to the Wordpress site after checkout?

Comment: Yes but they will login.  After checkout the first name, last name, email, and a password will come from Magento checkout.  At this time, the registration on the site I'm referring to, after registration a session variable is created before logging in.  And the variable is different for each user.

Comment: Can you tell me which file the session variable is created in... what function it is.....   When I do a search of the whole app I get 100s of files and haven't found it yet.

Comment: I'm still unsure as to where the session variable comes into play with the Wordpress site. If they're logging in with their credentials, Wordpress would create one when the user completes the login

Comment: Wordpress doesn't use sessions though, after researching, I saw it creates a cookie instead. Here's some info on using session variables with Wordpress: http://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/ good luck!

Comment: Thanks. The session variable is good now.  I figured that out.